# Animate SVG in loop with delay - safari

Tags: html, svg

I've created a basic svg animation which loops with delay, however once it's finished a single animation loop it jumps back to the beginning giving it an ugly hard cut look. This problem only occurs in safari.

```
<polygon id="obrys" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#1D1D1B" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="217.85,164.21 31,164.39 
    31.14,31.18 218.09,31       "/>

<g id="wing_all">
    <polygon id="wing_border_in" fill="none" stroke="#1D1D1B" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="195.41,142.85 
        53.82,142.76 53.68,52.14 195.26,52.23       "/>

    <polygon id="wing" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#1D1D1B" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="42.27,41.67 206.57,41.79 
        206.81,155.06 42.52,154.95      ">
        <animate 
            id="anim" 
            attributeName="points" 
            dur="0.2s"  
            fill="freeze"
            to="37.27,61.67 211.57,61.79 206.81,155.06 42.52,154.95" 
            begin="2s; anim_return.end+3"  />
        <animate 
            id="anim_return" 
            attributeName="points" 
            dur="0.2s" 
            fill="freeze"
            to="42.27,41.67 206.57,41.79 206.81,155.06 42.52,154.95" 
            begin="anim.end + 1s"  />
    </polygon>
</g>
```

[Example Codepen](https://codepen.io/uki150/pen/gzEoMz)

Comment: Not sure it is your issue but Didn't you forgot an `s` in `anim_return.end+3`?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: You could try setting attribute `accumulate="sum"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There indeed seems to be a bug in Safari's implementation, where the `fill="freeze"` of the first `<animate>` will override the animated value of the second one.

One way to workaround this issue is to make your animation through a single `<animate>`, unfortunately less clear, by using multiple `values`, and the `keyTimes` attribute.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 249.09 535.39"  width="200" height="500">
  <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#1D1D1B" stroke-width="2"
points="217.85,164.21 31,164.39 31.14,31.18 218.09,31"/>

  <g id="wing_all">
    <polygon fill="none" stroke="#1D1D1B" stroke-width="2"
      points="195.41,142.85 53.82,142.76 53.68,52.14 195.26,52.23"/>

    <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#1D1D1B" stroke-width="2" 
      points="42.27,41.67 206.57,41.79 206.81,155.06 42.52,154.95">
      <animate 
        attributeName="points" 
        dur="4.4s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
        values="42.27,41.67 206.57,41.79 206.81,155.06 42.52,154.95;
                37.27,61.67 211.57,61.79 206.81,155.06 42.52,154.95;
                37.27,61.67 211.57,61.79 206.81,155.06 42.52,154.95;
                42.27,41.67 206.57,41.79 206.81,155.06 42.52,154.95;
                42.27,41.67 206.57,41.79 206.81,155.06 42.52,154.95"
        keyTimes="0;0.045;0.272;0.318;1"
        begin="2s"/>
    </polygon>
  </g>
</svg>
```